# How to generate a CHANGELOG.md for a project using Plastic SCM?

Tags: plasticscm

As a front end developer, I'm used to work with Git and generate changelogs automatically using an [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) module named [standard-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-version). The generated changelog is based some [commit conventions](https://conventionalcommits.org), allowing the command line tool to group commits in categories (i.e. Features, Bug fixes, Breaking changes).

Today, our team is moving to Plastic SCM. Until now, the game programmers were writing changelogs manually.

Since this can be tedious most of the time, I was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing with Plastic SCM.

**Questions :**

1. Is there a tool available out of the box like *standard-version* ?
2. How can we retrieve a list of changesets between 2 labels (i.e. v2.0.0 -> v2.0.1) using the command line ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a tool available out of the box like standard-version ?

I'm afraid that there isn't something like *standard-version* provided by Plastic SCM out of the box. I guess it would be easy to port it to support Plastic as it currently does for Git.

> How can we retrieve a list of changesets between 2 labels (i.e. v2.0.0
>   -> v2.0.1) using the command line ?

The following doc entry covers it: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/cmfind/plastic-scm-version-control-query-system-guide.shtml#Findchangesetsbetween2labels

Comment: Thanks for your help !